# Alter IQueryable using expression?

Tags: odata, expression-trees, iqueryable

Im currently using OData to drive an API.
However Im exposing a DTO to the client that does some flatterning of the true entitys structure.. what would like to do is to be able to somehow "extract" the generated expression tree from the IQueryable that the OData query generates.

I have managed to extract the IQueryable thats generated.. but Im not entierly sure of how to extract the expression tree from an IQueryable.. and the only property Im aware of that exposes some kind of expression is the "Expression" property..however this property is of the type "Expression", which has no body.. so I guess I need to cast this to some other type of expression.. but Im not sure of which type to cast it to..

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to run your code and see what is actually the type of the expression?

Comment: why not using the debugger for this???

Comment: .Expression only returns  an object of type Expression.. so no matter if I run the code or simply debugg, its always returned as sn object of the type Expression, which is kind of anonymus for Me to be able to cast it to somthing that makes sense.

Comment: Every `Expression` has a `NodeType` property which tells you what type of expression the current instance represents...